# While trying to fetch data using findById(''), It got stuck

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

While trying to fetch data using findById() it gets stuck. If I am using correct ObjectID then it's returning data but If I am trying with Invalid ObjectID or empty string It got stuck.

If findById() should be called using invalid ObjectID it should return empty Object. But it's getting stuck there only. I have checked that by adding console.log()

### **Organization.mjs**

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const orgSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    org_name: { type: String, required: true },
    org_logo: { type: String },
    founded_on: { type: Date, required: true },
    founded_by: { type: String, required: true },
    active: { type: Boolean, default: true, required: true },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
export default mongoose.model("Organization", orgSchema);
```

### **db_connect.mjs**

```js
// Connection config
const dbConfig = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
};
export default () => {
  // Connect to db
  mongoose
    .connect(MONGODB_URI, dbConfig)
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Connected to db successfully...");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err.message);
    });
  // Listen to any error after connection
  mongoose.connection.on("error", (err) => {
    console.error(err.message);
  });
};
```

### **user_controller.mjs**

```js
import Organization from "../model/Organization.mjs";
export const createNewUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Check if org present or not
    const orgObject = await Organization.findById(req.body.org_id).exec();
    if (!orgObject) {
      return res.status(BAD_REQUEST).json(INVALID_ORG);
    }
    // TODO : Create user
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json(SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG);
  }
};
```

**Version**

```
Node.js : 12.18.1
Mongoose: 5.9.18
MongoDB: 4.2.8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what happened but after restarting my server. It started working.

Although it's throwing error as it's invalid id.

Answer (score 0):

`const orgObject = await Organization.findById(req.body.org_id).exec();`
Try to remove `.exec()`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but I have already tried this not working.

Comment: I know the answer, you are using ```res``` object in both try and catch. I don't think you function is a ```route``` so that's why it cannot return a response. In both cases you are trying to return response and you get nothing.

Comment: Or perhaps you want to use it as a middlware. I don't know if you do.

Comment: Please show the code where you are calling this function.

Comment: I was using a router. After restarting my server it starts working.

userRouter.post('/new', validate(newUserValidation, VALIDATOR_OPTIONS, {} ), createNewUser);